# Outsourcing DBA for MongoDB on AWS?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, database-administration, percona

So, I'm running MongoDB raw, manually installed on Red Hat linux on AWS.  I've been able to get installed, connected to web stack and rest of architecture, set up 3 EBS drives for each component.  It works great for development.  I don't have any sharding or really anything else other than the above.

I realize that, as I near production, I would never be able to provide the vigilant 24/7 monitoring and maintenance and fixing bad things that will inevitably happen.  Part of this is that I won't have time in general, and even if I did, the learning curve for optimized production MongoDB is too great to pick up on the fly.

So what I want is to pay someone else to do it for me.  I don't want the AWS managed NoSQL options, as I MUST, at this point (let's please accept this as an inflexible constraint for argument's sake), stick with MongoDB.  I can't use Rackspace, because they force you to buy EVERYTHING, including a lot of junk services I don't need.  I can't just buy MongoDB DBA with them.  I don't need help with anything else as it relates to my architecture on AWS (famous last words, but again, for argument's sake).

I looked @ Percona: their Outsourcing DBA is exactly what I want.  Then again, maybe I don't know what I want.  What are my other options here?  What do people do as they are straddling development and production?  Try to rely on a combination of their own knowledge/learning/AWS Developer support until they can pay a salaried employee?  What are the typical options short of that?  Paying some random freelancer on Upwork to do 24/7 maintenance on a contract basis (yikes)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but asking for advice on service contract selection

Comment: Indeed this is solicitation. +1 to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out these guys: https://mlab.com/ - MongoDB as a service.

and I agree your question is OT, but thought I'd give you a quick answer anyway before it gets closed.